# Custom C# XML/XSD from a classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

i am trying to get a xml from classes that i defined. This are my classes

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public MyAttribute[] Elements { get; set; }
}

public class MyAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
}


MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Name = "Class1";
myClass.Elements = new MyAttribute[3] {
    new MyAttribute(){ Name = "Att1", Value = 4 },
    new MyAttribute(){ Name = "Att2", Value = 5 },
    new MyAttribute(){ Name = "Att3", Value = 6 }
};
```

i would like get this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Class1>
  <Att1>4</Att1>
  <Att2>5</Att2>
  <Att3>6</Att3>
</Class1>
```

is possible generate this xml and his xsd. thanks.

**EDIT :**
I solved using XmlDocument class (System.Xml) like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyAttribute[] Elements { get; set; }

    public XmlDocument Xml()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement(this.Name);
        foreach (MyAttribute att in this.Elements)
        {
            XmlElement xmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement(att.Name);
            xmlElement.InnerText = att.Value.ToString();
            rootNode.AppendChild(xmlElement);
        }
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
        return xmlDoc;
    }
}
```

For XSD, I'm using XmlSchema (System.Xml.Schema)

Comment: Where is the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where is the database in Your description, but in order to create XML file from instances of Your classes, You can use [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) and [XmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx) attributes to decorate the classes and then serialize it as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813).

In order to create XSD, you can try to use XSD tool as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017422/232530).

**Edit**

In fact, looking at XML You want to get, You even don't have to use the attributes, just use `XmlSerializer` class as described in one of the links. For example, to save the generated XML to a string, You can use:

```
// before calling this code, create an instance of MyClass and fill properties with appropriate values
// let's assume the instance is named instanceOfMyClass

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
{
    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, instanceOfMyClass);
}

//now You can call stringBuilder.ToString() to get string with the serialized XML
```