# XSD generation from class, from code

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to write code that creates an XSD based on a C# class.

I can't find information how to do this without using XSD.exe. Example class:

```
[XmlRoot("Sync")]
public class SyncFileSettings : ISyncSettings
{
   public SyncFileSettings(int pingIntervalSec, bool useCompression)
    {
        PingIntervalSec = pingIntervalSec;
        UseCompression = useCompression;
    }

    public int PingIntervalSec { get; set; }
    public bool UseCompression { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Andreas try to edit more than removing just a single "tag" from a title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a XSD scheme from a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017139/how-to-create-a-xsd-scheme-from-a-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to generate xsd from class in code

[Using XSD.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017139/how-to-create-a-xsd-scheme-from-a-class).

> without XSD.exe?

Why? Then you'll have to reinvent the wheel, or [use a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386155/comparison-of-xsd-code-generators).

Comment: @Vladimir I can't really follow what you're saying. You can just run XSD.exe from code.

Comment: @Vladimir you're right, you're not allowed to redistribute XSD.exe. Why do you want your clients to generate an XSD though? Anyway to generate an XSD from a class is not trivial. Try searching for a library that allows you to do so.

Answer (score 2):

old thread, I know.

but now in the end of 2020 it was still hard for me to find a solution. I did, but it tooks a lot of time after I first found this thread. So - for all the guys finding just 'use XSD-tool' - there is a class
**XsdDataContractExporter** in .net 5.0 now (System.Runtime.Serialization)

easy going, see [microsoft XsdDataContractExporter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.xsddatacontractexporter?view=net-5.0). works fine!

happy coding :-)