# Converting specific C# classes into Xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd

I have a `project / dll`, which has a folder with set of `C# classes`, which need to be converted to `XSD file`. I have used `xsd.exe` tool bundled up with .Net framework to do it, but challenge remains, I cannot add specific C# types / classes  to be part of XSD file either it picks up every class in binary, using the following command:

```
xsd <exe / dll>
```

or if I do the following, I can at most supply one class / type:

```
 xsd <exe / dll> /t:<TypeName>
```

Any way to add specific C# classes, which I want to be part of XSD, as I cannot find a viable solution

Comment: may b this will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017139/how-to-create-a-xsd-schema-from-a-class

Comment: If you typed `/?` to display the tool's you'd see that you can supply multiple `/t` parameters. You could also check the tool's documentation. This *is* one of the oldest tools, available since 2002 and in fact, superceded by `svcutil` since 2005

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thanks, I tried help but somewhere missed out this part, since I was keen to supply multiple classes to same flag, please add this as an answer for me to accept it