# Convert class to XML

Tags: c#, xml, code-generation

Is there a way to generate XML structure from C# class definition?
Like "Edit/ Paste Special/ Paste XML as classes" in Visual Studio,
but in other direction.
For instance, from

```
public class Citizen
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int CountryId;
    [XmlElement]
    public Person Person;
}
```

get

```
<Citizen ContryId = "123">
    <Person>John Doe</Person>
</Citizen>
```

?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: Copy and paste your xml and press Convert buttion => https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: OK, thank you, I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: My spidey senses tell me there is an answer coming to this question very soon

Comment: you did vote to close -you voted as useful comment. you need 3K+ to vote to close

Comment: It´s not a dupe on StackOverflow (although I´m convinced there are plenty of similar questions). Just delete the question.

Comment: there must be a dup somewhere...

Comment: Yes, that's a correct dupe, not like the first one...

Comment: It is duplicate not of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml (see "class" - "object" difference ), but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017139/how-to-create-a-xsd-schema-from-a-class.

Comment: And comment suggesting xlm to C# convertion is plainly contrary to direction asked in question (c# to xml) :D

Comment: Removing "C#" from question title probably will make this question less visible in search

Comment: I updated the dup-link. It was not clear to me if you wanted just the xml-**data**, or actually the xml-**schema**. Your example seemed like the former.