# Links between multiple xsd schemas in one document

Tags: xsd, xsd.exe

I have four xsd schemas where one use types from another three. I want to unite them in one document but xs:import with specified namesapces doesn't work: xsd.exe writes "Type ... is not declared". How to make links between multiple xsd schemas in one document?

**Upd:**
I have this http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticc_v1p0.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imsbasiclti_v1p0.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticm_v1p0.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticp_v1p0.xsd 
I downloaded them and execute in command prompt

```
>xsd imslticc_v1p0.xsd imsbasiclti_v1p0.xsd imslticm_v1p0.xsd imslticp_v1p0.xsd /classes
```

It works great but I need single xsd.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @helderdarocha I've updated description.

Comment: Add the XSD you are trying to write, the one that imports/includes those schemas.

Comment: Where do you get that error? When you use it with some instance? Which one? I used `<xs:import>` on those 4 schemas and the resulting one validates OK. Is that all you need? To use a XSD with imported schemas you will have to deal with the namespaces in your instances. If the error related to validation, please include a sample instance.

Comment: @helderdarocha I've just copy this schemas and insert into one file and tried to execute xsd.exe for it.

Comment: See the solution I posted. Did you try anything like that? It validates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to combine your four schemas into one. You will still have to deal with the individual namespaces when validating your instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticc_v1p0.xsd" 
        namespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslticc_v1p0"/>
    <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imsbasiclti_v1p0.xsd"
        namespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsbasiclti_v1p0"/>
    <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticm_v1p0.xsd" 
        namespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslticm_v1p0"/>
    <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticp_v1p0.xsd" 
        namespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslticp_v1p0"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This validates this instance successfully:

```
<lticc:cartridge_basiclti_link xmlns:lticc="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslticc_v1p0"
    xmlns:basiclti="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsbasiclti_v1p0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="multi-schema.xsd">
    <basiclti:title></basiclti:title>
    <basiclti:description></basiclti:description>
    <basiclti:custom></basiclti:custom>
    <basiclti:extensions platform="x"></basiclti:extensions>
    <basiclti:launch_url>http://some-url.com</basiclti:launch_url>
    <basiclti:secure_launch_url>https://some-url.com</basiclti:secure_launch_url>
    <basiclti:icon></basiclti:icon>
    <basiclti:secure_icon></basiclti:secure_icon>
    <basiclti:vendor>
        <code xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslticp_v1p0">x</code>
        <name xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslticp_v1p0"></name>
    </basiclti:vendor>
</lticc:cartridge_basiclti_link>
```

Comment: I've tried to execute xsd.ex for it and got "cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type were found". But http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/lti/ltiv1p0/imslticc_v1p0.xsd schema contains element!

Comment: The schema imports are correct. There are no validation problems. I will add an example of a XML instance that it validates. The problem seems to be due to a restriction imposed by `xsd.exe` which requires at least one `xs:element` in order to generate types. Perhaps it requires some configuration do deal with the imported namespaces, or you might have to workaround some limitations of the tool (See [here](http://goo.gl/MeIRRh), [here](http://goo.gl/JsZz36) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054687/error-when-generating-a-class-from-xsd-schema-file)).

Comment: Thank you for help, but now I have problem with validation. This example of xml for my xsd https://www.edu-apps.org/tools/noteflight/config.xml?domain=myschool (more examples here https://www.edu-apps.org/index.html). But this xml are not valid.

Comment: Your XML is not valid because some elements are out of order (it seems that `launch_url` should come before `icon`) and others seem to be misplaced. You have to check the individual schemas and see what are the rules to build instances.